# Unable to use painless in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have the following query, which is using painless script to create a script_score,
which is used for sorting.

**Following are my creation scripts -**

```
PUT /listings/_doc/1
{
  "prod_id" : 1,
  "currency" : "USD",
  "price" : 1
}

PUT /listings/_doc/2
{
  "prod_id" : 2,
  "currency" : "INR",
  "price" : 60
}

PUT /listings/_doc/3
{
  "prod_id" : 3,
  "currency" : "EUR",
  "price" : 2
}

PUT /listings/_doc/4
{
  "prod_id" : 5,
  "currency" : "MYR",
  "price" : 1
}
```

**The data looks like this -**

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "prod_id" : 1,
          "currency" : "USD",
          "price" : 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "prod_id" : 2,
          "currency" : "INR",
          "price" : 60
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "prod_id" : 3,
          "currency" : "EUR",
          "price" : 2
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "prod_id" : 5,
          "currency" : "MYR",
          "price" : 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**The query that I'm trying to run -**

```
GET products/_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "functions": [{
                "script_score": {
                    "script": {
                        "params": {
                            "usd": 1,
                            "isCheckOutUsd" : true,
                            "sgdBuy": 0.72,
                            "sgdSpot": 0.72,
                            "myrBuy": 0.24,
                            "myrSpot": 0.24,
                            "inrBuy": 0.014,
                            "inrSpot": 0.014,
                            "eurBuy": 1.12,
                            "eurSpot": 1.12
                        },
                         "source": """
                            double valueForComparision = 0;

                            if(doc.currency.value == 'usd'){
                                valueForComparision = doc.price.value;
                            }
                            else{
                                if(params.isCheckOutUsd){
                                    String temp = doc.currency.value + "Buy";       
                                    valueForComparision = doc.price.value / params[temp];
                                }
                                else{
                                    String temp = doc.currency.value + "Spot";      
                                    valueForComparision = doc.price.value / params[temp];
                                }
                            }
                            return valueForComparision;     
                        """
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm following this doc as a reference -
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-walkthrough.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if condition needs to be a boolean

Change this

```
if('isCheckOutUsd')
```

To this:

```
if(params.isCheckOutUsd)
```

Comment: getting a different error now, updated the question

Comment: You're missing and opening curly brace after `if(params.isCheckOutUsd)`

Comment: getting `wrong_method_type_exception`, will I be able to get `eurBuy in temp`

Comment: change the type of `valueForComparision` to `long` instead of `int`

Comment: class_cast_exception

Comment: Not sure what `doc.price.value / 'temp'` is  supposed to do but you cannot divide a long by a String (see the error message)

Comment: actually, temp is supposed to be `eurBuy` or `eurSpot` from the params

Comment: Well, then, go ahead !

Comment: I should remove the `'` around temp yes? like normal variable?

Comment: quotes delimit a string, so yes.

Comment: was able to resolve, thanks for helping with the errors, updated answer in the question